# Tonelli's theorem for almost everywhere nonnegative

Tags: measure-theory

Can we apply Tonelli's theorem on a measurable function that is nonnegative almost everywhere"?

Comment: Yes. What holds almost everywhere can be assume to hold everywhere. Or, if you prefer, what holds on a negligible set can be neglected. Of course, you must be sure that the function is non-negative almost everywhere *w.r.t. the product measure*. For instance, knowing that $\forall x,\,\tilde\forall y,\, f(x,y)\ge0$ is **not** sufficient.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: If $f$ is measurable w.r.t. the product $\sigma$ algebra and if all measures in question are $\sigma$-finite, it is (essentially by Fubini).

Comment: Thanks, @phoemuex, I did not know that. I assumed almost automatically that there was some weird counterexample (though I could only think of non-measurable ones).